# How to set up one way sync AWS S3 bucket to Azure Blob storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

We have a use case where we need to set up replication of data files (PDF,xml,html) from AWS S3 bucket to Azure Blob storage or Data Lake

we have explored **Data factory**, **AzCopy** and **Rclone** but none of them fits in to my use case. It does not fit into my use case because we need to schedule it and scheduling will have added latency.
My use case is auto sync between s3 and azure blob.
My application latency driven application so as soon as files are saved into s3 should move to azure blob immediately (expected latency is 1 to 5 sec for 100 Kb file).

The data files we receive in s3 is 200K per day, and all should be moved as and when we get files in s3.

The last Option that we have is to write one application that will move data from s3 to Azure, but before that we are exploring if any inbuilt solution, we have either from AWS side or specially in Azure side?